# How to draw with button click- C++ Windows Forms

Tags: c++, windows, forms

In a C++ WIndows Form 2010, I need to draw a line inside a Panel when a button is clicked. I  know how to draw a line in the paint but in `GO_Click` member not.

```
private: System::Void GO_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    m->DrawLine(Pens::Blue, 500, 550, 700, 500);
}
```

How to use DrawLine in GO_Click member?

Comment: I used below code to draw a line in the panel. I thought may it works in the GO_Click too. I am new in Windows Forms                                                       Graphics^ m = e->Graphics;
m->DrawLine(Pens::Blue, 500, 550, 700, 500);

Answer (score 1):

Look at this sample:

```
    private: System::Void GO_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        // This works, but the drawn line will be lost when refreshing the panel etc.

        //Graphics^ g = panel1->CreateGraphics();
        //g->DrawLine(System::Drawing::Pens::Blue, 500, 550, 700, 500);

        // This approach draws the line on the BackroungImage of the panel
        if (panel1->BackgroundImage == nullptr)
        {
            panel1->BackgroundImage = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(panel1->Width, panel1->Height);
        }

        Graphics^ buffGraphics = Graphics::FromImage(panel1->BackgroundImage);

        buffGraphics->Clear(panel1->BackColor);
        buffGraphics->DrawLine(System::Drawing::Pens::Blue, 500, 550, 700, 500);

        panel1->Update();
    }
```

**But**, there are much more ways to draw the line.